# All three if statements in a for loop triggering when only one is true (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

This has me a little stumped. Whenever I execute this code, if one of the `if` statements in the `for` loop are true, all three sub-arrays of `weaknessArray` get effected. The same thing happens when each `if` statement is in it's own `for` loop and if instead of one 2D array I use a three separate arrays, one for each `for` loop.

```
var typeChart = [2,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,2,2,2,2];
var blankArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var weaknessArray = [blankArray,blankArray,blankArray];

for(i = 0; i<18; i++){
if(typeChart[i] === 0) weaknessArray[2][i] = 1;
if(typeChart[i] === 1) weaknessArray[1][i] = 1;
if(typeChart[i] === 4) weaknessArray[0][i] = 1;

console.log(weaknessArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only ever one `blankArray` object in memory; your `weaknessArray` contains three references to the *same object*.

Create copies instead with `.slice`, so that you have three arrays (well, four, counting the original) in memory instead of one:

```js
var typeChart = [2,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,2,2,2,2];
var blankArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var weaknessArray = [blankArray.slice(), blankArray.slice(), blankArray.slice()];

for(i = 0; i<18; i++){
  if(typeChart[i] === 0) weaknessArray[2][i] = 1;
  if(typeChart[i] === 1) weaknessArray[1][i] = 1;
  if(typeChart[i] === 4) weaknessArray[0][i] = 1;

  console.log(weaknessArray);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This had me stumped for the longest time